# UITableView second load does not update until scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a view and a tableview which it shows file list. When user click button in view then I open tableview. User click the file list row then I started to download file from my server and when download start I changed the file name like "11111", when download finish change file name like "22222" (now change the file name later I will put progress view)
In first run everything is working correctly. Download and change name working. But in tableview when I come back to view and go to tableview again, download is working but not change then file name in tableview.

What is wrong in my code and how can I show text value?

PS: When print the text value in tableview before return cell, it shows correct text.

My codes:

```
func setProgressValue(_ dict : NSDictionary){

    //Download progress value
    let cellProgressValue = dict.value(forKey: "value") as! Float

    if cellProgressValue < 1.0{

         fileList[cellNum].title = "111111"
         updateTable()
    }
    else{

        fileList[cellNum].title = “22222”
        updateTable()   
    }
}

func updateTable(){

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return fileList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let identifier = "fileCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.fileList[indexPath.row].title

        return cell
    }
```

//Call in viewdidload
    func getFiles(){

```
        for index in songList{

            let urlString = "https://www.myapis.com/data/files"

            Alamofire.request(urlString).validate().responseJSON { response in

                let result = JSON(response.result.value)

                    if let items = result["items"].array {

                        for item in items {

                            //print(item)

                            let id = item["fileId"].stringValue
                            let title = ["fileName"].stringValue

                            let file = Files()
                            file.id = id
                            file.title = title

                            self.fileList.append(song)
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }                
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: reload tableview in main Queue

Comment: I tried it with DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }) and not working.

Comment: you are getting file in viewdidload move it into viewWillAppear

Comment: Nothing change still not change text on second load –